# Print environment variables of all users

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I searched everywhere on the internet to find a way of displaying all environment variables of all users (as root) on a linux server.

I tried to write a script to run `env` or `printenv` as every user available on the system but I would like to know an easier way to do it.

Can you help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: How about using find /proc -name "environ" -exec cat '{}' \;

Answer (score 0):

AFAIC you can't fetch it for all users atonce using single command, but for single user:

```
# RHEL
sudo -Hiu $USER env

# Deb
su - $USER -c 'printenv'
```

Knowing this you can create script, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for USER in $(grep /home /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1)
do
  echo "==== User: ${USER}"
  su - $USER -c 'printenv'
done
```

Comment: Hello Facty and thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunetly I'm afraid that sudo is not installed because I get "sudo command not found". I might be missing something, but can't I do this as root without using "sudo" ?

Comment: Interesting :) .... then you can try `su - $user -c 'printenv'` What kind of distro do you use?

Comment: I'm using Debian 9. It works like a charm now, thank you very much for you time, it helped me a lot ! :) Using `su` was exactly what I was missing !

Comment: Glad to help and return effort back to community :)